# Create Download Link for one column in dynamic html table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a table coming from database. i want to create a download for

> Resume  column

in the table and it should download or view that particular row file. How can I do that.

[image]

**jobs.php**

```
     <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <h3 style="text-align: center">Job Application Submitted</h3>
    <table>
  <thead>
  <tr class="table-headers">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>job Applied For</th>
    <th>Resume</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
      <tbody>
<?php include('config.php');


  $sql = "SELECT * FROM apply_job order by id ASC";
  $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

  {

?>    


    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['template-jobform-fname']?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['template-jobform-email'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['template-jobform-phone'];?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['job_name'];?></td>
     <td><a href="<?php echo $row['template-jobform-application']?>" target="_blank" ><?php echo $row['template-jobform-application'];?></a></td>

    </tr>
   <?php 
}
}
?>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I wanted a download for particular file that is if i update second row and download second row resume it should download that particular resume not all. How can I do that.

Comment: so the problem is, that when you click on the link `href="<?php echo $row['template-jobform-application']?>"` _all_ files get downloaded?? Did I understand that right? Or is the content of the link/file wrong?

Comment: Where are you storing your pdf's? Directly in the database as raw data or is it in any folder?

Answer (score 1):

```
Use sample function below for file download
<?php
function fileDownload($filename, $filepath)
{
    $filepath = $filepath . "/" . $filename;
    header("Cache-control: private");
    header("Content-type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-transfer-encoding: binary\n");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filepath));
    readfile($filepath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a download link like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $row['template-jobform-application']?>" download ><?php echo $row['template-jobform-application'];?></a>
```

Note the presence of the `download` attribute inside the tag definition, which specifies that the target should be downloaded on click.